# c++ float subtraction rounding error

Tags: c++, floating-point

I have a float value between 0 and 1. I need to convert it with -120 to 80. 
To do this, first I multiply with 200 after 120 subtract. 
When subtract is made I had rounding error. 
Let's look my example.

```
    float val = 0.6050f;
    val *= 200.f;
```

Now val is 121.0 as I expected.

```
    val -= 120.0f;
```

Now val is 0.99999992

I thought maybe I can avoid this problem with multiplication and division.

```
    float val = 0.6050f;
    val *= 200.f;
    val *= 100.f;
    val -= 12000.0f;    
    val /= 100.f;
```

But it didn't help. I have still 0.99 on my hand.

Is there a solution for it?

Edit: After with detailed logging, I understand there is no problem with this part of code. Before my log shows me "0.605", after I had detailed log and I saw "0.60499995946884155273437500000000000000000000000000" 
the problem is in different place.

Edit2: I think I found the guilty. The initialised value is 0.5750.

```
std::string floatToStr(double d)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::fixed << std::setprecision(15) << d;
    return ss.str();
}

int main()
{    
    float val88 = 0.57500000000f;
    std::cout << floatToStr(val88) << std::endl;
}
```

The result is 0.574999988079071

Actually I need to add and sub 0.0025 from this value every time. 
Normally I expected 0.575, 0.5775, 0.5800, 0.5825 ....

Edit3: Actually I tried all of them with double. And it is working for my example.

```
std::string doubleToStr(double d)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::fixed << std::setprecision(15) << d;
    return ss.str();
}

int main()
{    
    double val88 = 0.575;
    std::cout << doubleToStr(val88) << std::endl;
    val88 += 0.0025;
    std::cout << doubleToStr(val88) << std::endl;
    val88 += 0.0025;
    std::cout << doubleToStr(val88) << std::endl;
    val88 += 0.0025;
    std::cout << doubleToStr(val88) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The results are:

```
0.575000000000000
0.577500000000000
0.580000000000000
0.582500000000000
```

But I bound to float unfortunately. I need to change lots of things.

Thank you for all to help.

Edit4: I have found my solution with strings. I use ostringstream's rounding and convert to double after that. I can have 4 precision right numbers.

```
std::string doubleToStr(double d, int precision)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::fixed << std::setprecision(precision) << d;
    return ss.str();
}

    double val945 = (double)0.575f;
    std::cout << doubleToStr(val945, 4) << std::endl;
    std::cout << doubleToStr(val945, 15) << std::endl;
    std::cout << atof(doubleToStr(val945, 4).c_str()) << std::endl;
```

and results are:

```
0.5750
0.574999988079071
0.575
```

Comment: Too bad, it's floating point. There will always be inaccuracies.

Comment: @nneonneo: There won't *always* be inaccuracies if you restrict all your calculations to number that happen to be exactly representable (basically integer multiples of powers of 2.0). But `0.6050f` is not such a value.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.22.6768)

Comment: The more operations you do a floating point value, the bigger the rounding errors will get.

Comment: `0.6050.f` is a syntax error. I think you mean `0.6050f`. Please copy-and-paste exact code.

Comment: use double and try again.

Comment: I can't reproduce your results. That's not your real code, is it?

Comment: In addtion:  http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/floating-pt-errs.html

Comment: @40two I feel like that one should be required reading for stack overflow :-P

Comment: I already tried double. I correct the mistake 0.6050.f. Yes, it is not real code.

Comment: Another two cents, the only way around this is to not use floats. Floats are approximations by definition, but the range of numbers you're looking at can all be stored in a 32 bit fixed point number.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams Necessary prerequisite.

Comment: @Volkan I don't see any way somebody can solve your problem then with what's given in the question.

Comment: @Volkan Not an answer, merely trying to get you to divulge more information so a specific answer can be made rather than directing you to floating point resources.

Comment: @remyabel I was a little bit aggressive to you. I am sorry.

Answer (score 6):

Let us assume that your compiler implements IEEE 754 binary32 and binary64 exactly for `float` and `double` values and operations.

First, you must understand that `0.6050f` does not represent the mathematical quantity 6050 / 10000. It is exactly `0.605000019073486328125`, the nearest `float` to that. Even if you write perfect computations from there, you have to remember that these computations start from 0.605000019073486328125 and not from 0.6050.

Second, you can solve nearly all your accumulated roundoff problems by computing with `double` and converting to `float` only in the end:

```
$ cat t.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  printf("0.6050f is %.53f\n", 0.6050f);
  printf("%.53f\n", (float)((double)0.605f * 200. - 120.));
}

$ gcc t.c && ./a.out 
0.6050f is 0.60500001907348632812500000000000000000000000000000000
1.00000381469726562500000000000000000000000000000000000
```

In the above code, all computations and intermediate values are double-precision.

This `1.0000038…` is a very good answer if you remember that you started with 0.605000019073486328125 and not 0.6050 (which doesn't exist as a `float`).

Comment: Downvoter, any comment to go together with the downvote? Any factual error in the above?

Comment: I tried your example with hard code, 0.6050f come from another place but I put hard code and it worked well. I write audio plugin and I can't use std::cout. I use logging system and when 0.6050f come, I put with logging system to a file. It writes "0.605". But I need to debug this value I think.

Comment: @VolkanOzyilmaz That's great. My specialty is -1 score answers which actually helped the asker.

Comment: Isn't it possible to convert correctly to double from float? 

double val945 = (double)0.575f;
std::cout << doubleToStr(val945) << std::endl;

result is still: 0.574999988079071

Comment: @VolkanOzyilmaz The conversion from `float` to `double` is usually lossless (“usually” meaning “under the same assumptions as in the question”). `0.575f` is already a value in fact close to 0.574999988079071. You cannot **recover** information by converting it to `double`, because the information is already lost.

Comment: In double precision, the closest value to .6050 is .60499999999999998, the next closest value is .60500000000000009 . So in the case of double precision, .6050 is rounded down slightly.

Answer (score 2):

If you really care about the difference between 0.99999992 and 1.0, `float` is not precise enough for your application. You need to at least change to `double`.

If you need an answer in a specific range, and you are getting answers slightly outside that range but within rounding error of one of the ends, replace the answer with the appropriate range end.

Answer (score 2):

The point everybody is making can be summarised: in general, **floating point is *precise* but not *exact***.

How *precise* is governed by the number of bits in the mantissa -- which is 24 for float, and 53 for double (assuming IEEE 754 binary formats, which is pretty safe these days !  [1]).

If you are looking for an *exact* result, you have to be ready to deal with values that differ (ever so slightly) from that exact result, but...

---

**(1) The Exact Binary Fraction Problem**

...the *first* issue is whether the exact value you are looking for can be represented *exactly* in binary floating point form...

...and that is *rare* -- which is often a disappointing surprise.

The binary floating point representation of a given value can be exact, but only under the following, *restricted* circumstances:

- the value is an integer, < 2^24 (float) or < 2^53 (double).

  this is the simplest case, and perhaps obvious.  Since you are looking a result >= -120 and <= 80, this is sufficient.

or:

- the value is an integer which divides exactly by 2^n and is then (as above) < 2^24 or < 2^53.

  this includes the first rule, but is more general.

or:

- the value has a fractional part, but when the value is multiplied by the smallest 2^n necessary to produce an integer, that integer is < 2^24 (float) or 2^53 (double).

  This is the part which may come as a surprise.

  Consider 27.01, which is a simple enough decimal value, and clearly well within the ~7 decimal digit precision of a float.  *Unfortunately*, it does not have an exact *binary* floating point form -- you can multiply 27.01 by any 2^n you like, for example:

  ```
    27.01 * (2^ 6) =      1728.64   (multiply by  64)
    27.01 * (2^ 7) =      3457.28   (multiply by 128)
    ...
    27.01 * (2^10) =     27658.24
    ...
    27.01 * (2^20) =  28322037.76
    ...
    27.01 * (2^25) = 906305208.32  (> 2^24 !)
  ```

  and you *never* get an integer, let alone one < 2^24 or < 2^53.

  Actually, all these rules boil down to one rule... if you can find an 'n' (positive or negative, integer) such that `y = value * (2^n)`, and where `y` is an *exact*, *odd* integer, then `value` has an exact representation if y < 2^24 (float) or if y < 2^53 (double) -- assuming no under- or over-flow, which is another story.

This looks complicated, but the rule of thumb is simply: "**very few decimal fractions can be represented exactly as binary fractions**".

To illustrate **how few**, let us consider all the 4 digit decimal fractions, of which there are 10000, that is 0.0000 up to 0.9999 -- including the trivial, integer case 0.0000.  We can *enumerate* how many of those have exact binary equivalents:

```
   1: 0.0000 =  0/16 or 0/1
   2: 0.0625 =  1/16
   3: 0.1250 =  2/16 or 1/8
   4: 0.1875 =  3/16
   5: 0.2500 =  4/16 or 1/4
   6: 0.3125 =  5/16
   7: 0.3750 =  6/16 or 3/8
   8: 0.4375 =  7/16
   9: 0.5000 =  8/16 or 1/2
  10: 0.5625 =  9/16
  11: 0.6250 = 10/16 or 5/8
  12: 0.6875 = 11/16
  13: 0.7500 = 12/16 or 3/4
  14: 0.8125 = 13/16
  15: 0.8750 = 14/16 or 7/8
  16: 0.9375 = 15/16
```

That's it !  Just **16/10000** possible 4 digit decimal fractions (*including* the *trivial* 0 case) have exact binary fraction equivalents, at **any** precision.  All the other 9984/10000 possible decimal fractions give rise to *recurring* binary fractions.  So, for 'n' digit decimal fractions only `(2^n) / (10^n)` can be represented exactly -- that's `1/(5^n)` !!

This is, of course, because your decimal fraction is actually the rational `x / (10^n)`[2] and your binary fraction is `y / (2^m)` (for integer x, y, n and m), and for a given binary fraction to be exactly equal to a decimal fraction we must have:

```
  y = (x / (10^n)) * (2^m)   
    = (x / ( 5^n)) * (2^(m-n))
```

which is only the case when `x` is an exact multiple of `(5^n)` -- for otherwise `y` is not an integer.  (Noting that `n` <= `m`, assuming that `x` has no (spurious) trailing zeros, and hence `n` is as small as possible.)

---

**(2) The Rounding Problem**

The result of a floating point operation may need to be rounded to the precision of the destination variable.  IEEE 754 requires that the operation is done as if there were no limit to the precision, and the ("true") result is then rounded to the nearest value at the precision of the destination.  So, the final result is as precise as it can be... given the limitations on how precise the arguments are, and how precise the destination is... but *not exact* !

(With floats and doubles, 'C' may promote float arguments to double (or long double) before performing an operation, and the result of that will be rounded to double.  The final result of an expression may then be a double (or long double), which is then rounded (again) if it is to be stored in a float variable.  All of this adds to the fun !  See FLT_EVAL_METHOD for what your system does -- noting the default for a floating point constant is double.)

So, the other rules to remember are:

- **floating point values are not reals** (they are, in fact, rationals with a limited denominator).

  The precision of a floating point value may be large, but there are lots of real numbers that cannot be represented exactly !
- **floating point expressions are not algebra**.

  For example, converting from degrees to radians requires division by *π*.  Any arithmetic with *π* has a problem ('cos it's irrational), and with floating point the value for *π* is rounded to whatever floating precision we are using.  So, the conversion of (say) 27 (which is exact) degrees to radians involves division by 180 (which is exact) and multiplication by our "*π*".  However exact the arguments, the division and the multiplication may round, so the result is may only approximate.  Taking:

  ```
      float pi = 3.14159265358979 ;   /* plenty for float */
      float  x = 27.0 ;
      float  y = (x / 180.0) * pi ;
      float  z = (y / pi) * 180.0 ;

      printf("z-x = %+6.3e\n", z-x) ;
  ```

  my (pretty ordinary) machine gave: "z-x = +1.907e-06"... so, for our floating point:

  ```
  x != (((x / 180.0) * pi) / pi) * 180 ;
  ```

  at least, not for all `x`.  In the case shown, the relative difference is small -- ~ 1.2 / (2^24) -- but not zero, which simple algebra might lead us to expect.
- hence: **floating point equality is a slippery notion**.

  For all the reasons above, the test `x == y` for two floating values is problematic.  Depending on how `x` and `y` have been calculated, if you expect the two to be exactly the same, you may very well be sadly disappointed.

---

[1] There exists a standard for decimal floating point, but generally binary floating point is what people use.

[2] For any decimal fraction you can write down with a finite number of digits !

Answer (score 0):

Even with double precision, you'll run into issues such as:

```
200. * .60499999999999992 = 120.99999999999997
```

It appears that you want some type of rounding so that 0.99999992 is rounded to 1.00000000 .

If the goal is to produce values to the nearest multiple of 1/1000, try:

```
#include <math.h>

    val = (float) floor((200000.0f*val)-119999.5f)/1000.0f;
```

If the goal is to produce values to the nearest multiple of 1/200, try:

```
    val = (float) floor((40000.0f*val)-23999.5f)/200.0f;
```

If the goal is to produce values to the nearest integer, try:

```
    val = (float) floor((200.0f*val)-119.5f);
```